# Auth0 React Quickstart Login Not Working, 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, auth0

I’m having some trouble with the react quickstart for basic login and logout using auth0 . The allowed callback URLs is set to http://localhost:3000, and so is the allowed logout urls, allowed web origins, and allowed origins (CORS). I also set my application type to SPA, but whenever I login in I get back a 401 error response of `{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}`

Comment: Seeing this too, not sure what I'm missing!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue. Fixed by setting `Authentication Method` to `None` in the auth0 dashboard.

Found similar questions as well

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64351399/9640177
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64029906/9640177

Comment: I also have the same problem, but `Authentication Method` it's already set to `None` when using SPA configuration