# Login with Auth0 was successful but still a 401 'access denied' is returned?

Tags: auth0

I managed to get Auth0 somewhat working for my Vue.js app. The Quickstart Guide was straight forward.
So what happened is that I managed to use the login functionality and was prompted with the Auth0 Login dialog. I used my google account to do a quick-login. That also worked. My google account was now visible as a new user in my Auth0 Dashboard.

However after the login I was returned to my Vue.js app but the authorization was not successful it seems.

The network tab tells me the following:

```
{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}
```

I was wondering if I have to give the user some roles or permissions before he is considered as 'authorized'? My impression was that this will be true by default and only restricted if I start defining roles in the Auth0 Dashboard.

Please enlighten me!

PS: I am using the non-implict login dialog provided by Auth0 while I am working on a SPA. I read that might cause troubles?

PS 2: [image]

And the Raw Data of the 'Failed Exchange' Log:

```
{
  "date": "2020-08-24T10:43:52.005Z",
  "type": "feacft",
  "description": "Unauthorized",
  "connection_id": "",
  "client_id": "<Client_ID>",
  "client_name": null,
  "ip": "85.197.56.111",
  "user_agent": "Chrome 83.0.4103 / Linux 0.0.0",
  "details": {
    "code": "*************T8a"
  },
  "hostname": "alemanni-game.eu.auth0.com",
  "user_id": "",
  "user_name": "",
  "log_id": "90020200824104353383000015217913666506642073534760747026",
  "_id": "90020200824104353383000015217913666506642073534760747026",
  "isMobile": false
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had this issue and was finally able to find out the cause of this issue. I came across this question while I was searching for the solution to this problem but it hadn't been answered. As I was able to solve the problem, so I decided to answer this question.

---

In my case, the problem was that the token endpoint was returning the status code of `401` with `unauthorized/access denied` error and this seems to be the problem in your case too.

Problem was because of the incorrect value of **"Token Endpoint Authentication Method"** in the application settings.

[image]

In the case of single page applications, its value should be **"None"** but it was incorrectly set to **"POST"**.

It seems that we cannot change its value, so I just created a new application and selected **"Single Page Web Applications"** as the application type. This solved the issue.

Comment: This worked for me as well. What you can also do, is change the type to machine-to-machine, set it to `None`, and then change it back to PWA

Comment: You sir are a genius. This has taken me hours to track down. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, this took me way to long to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is still present, and the solution still valid <3 . But now one can change the value to None on the Credentials Tab :

[Change to None on Credentials tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooXma.png)

I had to change this to get my Svelte App finally running.